# How do I add a Web URL to a document using LotusScript

Tags: hyperlink, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an agent that takes a copy of a template document and puts in values from a text file.

I am running into a problem when adding a hyperlink to a field programmatically, If I just add the text (e.g. http://www.google.com) there is no hyperlink just plain text. If I add the text manually, by editing the document just adding the address works fine and is clickable.

I have tried creating a rich text object then adding that to the field but that doesn't work either :(

```
Set rtItem = New NotesRichTextItem( doc, "link" )
Call rtitem.AddNewLine( 1 )
Call rtItem.AppendText ("http://www.google.com")
doc.AppendItemValue "Details", rtItem
```

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to append a clickable hyperlink to a field using lotusscript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Upon further inspection if I generate a document with a link in the text field and save it (programmatically using doc.save) it saves as plain text, as soon as I then go into this document and do a manual save the plain text turns into a link just fine. Could something be wrong with how I am saving?

```
If  (Not doc.save(True,False,True)) Then
    Msgbox("Document could not save")
End If
```

Comment: Have a look at my [**answer here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549350/1047998) on how to make URLs clickable via Lotus Notes preferences.

Comment: @naveen Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think its a client a client issue as I am able to add the url manually (by typing in the relevant field) but not by adding it with my agent using     doc.AppendItemValue "Details", rtItem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work the way you tried in your code with just "AppendText". But, the link works only if the document is in **read mode** and client property "Make Internet URL ... into Hotspots" is set.

[image]

UPDATE:

`AppendItemValue` doesn't work for RichTextItems.

Append the link direct to your field "Details" or if it doesn't exist then create it. Your code should look like this:

```vb
Dim rtItem As NotesRichTextItem
If doc.Hasitem("Details") Then 
    Set rtitem = doc.Getfirstitem("Details")
Else 
    Set rtitem = doc.Createrichtextitem("Details")
End if
Call rtitem.AddNewLine( 1 )
Call rtItem.AppendText ("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I doubt it is a client issue as when I add the address by editing the document manually it shows fine. I am also sure I am in read mode for the document

Comment: Knut is correct.  AppendItem value is treating your Details field like a plain text item instead of a rich text item.  When you edit and save the document, it is being converted back to a rich text item. You can probably get that to happen by calling doc.ComputeWithForm before doc.Save, but that really is the wrong way to be doing things. You should be doing Set rtItem = New NotesRichTextItem( doc, "Details" ) instead of Set rtItem = New NotesRichTextItem( doc, "link" ), and just get rid of the call to AppendItemValue.